# Como hacer login en una pagina utilizando cURL PHP

Tags: php, login, curl

Estoy tratando de renderizar información en una pagina desde otra, pero para esto necesito hacer login a la pagina externa para importar el nombre de usuario y otras características del perfil.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente...

```
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5';
$url = "https://ejemplo.com/login";
$data = array(
    "userId"=> "user"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

El problema es que me da un 403 forbidden

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 Forbidden</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/es-mx/error.html</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Forbidden</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet-48f4f9e8</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Para hacer login en esa página es necesario primero ingresar el usuario y te redirige a una segunda pagina para poner la contraseña, el problema es que no eh pasado siquiera del usuario. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: estas conectandote a "https://ejemplo.com/login" la url esta mal deberia ser http y localhost...